# Google Data Studio: Refreshing data of uploaded CSV file

Tags: looker-studio

I have uploaded a csv file. The dashboards show this data. However if the data in the csv file is updated the data is not refreshed either automatically after 12 hours or by pressing the "Data Refresh" button. How can I get he dashboards to reflect the updated data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are uploading the CSV from your local computer, Data Studio **will not** get updated with any changes you made later in the CSV.

You can use Google Sheets to store your data, instead of `Upload a CSV file` as the data source, you can `import the data from Google Sheets` to Data Studio.

Any updates on the Google Sheets will be refreshed on Data Studio after you click the `Data Refresh` button or wait for the default data updates which are *15 minutes*.